# chromeDriver window crushes during wait.until() C# selenium

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I'm having a bit difficulties with chrome driver and selenium, i have selenium.support version 3.141.0 and chrome driver version 2.43.0.

during a test run i click on a button which redirect me to a new page, so i use WebDriverWait.until() until a condition that check if a certain element exist is met but for reason the window is flashing for a few seconds and later just close.

```
_wait.Until(d => d.FindElements(By.XPath("//div[@id = 'expression']")).Any());
```

edit: i found that the window is flashing and later shut down after this line which come after the wait.Until.

```
_driver.FindElements(By.ClassName("connections-list")).First();
```

the line return Sequence contains no elements although the element is visible and it still doesnt explain why the window shut down

Comment: Do you have any exceptions?

Comment: Yes, Sequence contains no elements

Answer (score 1):

Suggest you to use External supported library, And check your scenario with same:

**Library :** **SeleniumExtras.WaitHelpers**

You can use it as:

`wait.Until(SeleniumExtras.WaitHelpers.ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible(WebElement));`